# Subdomain and virtual host

Tags: apache

I have two sub domains: sinology.mydomain.com and application.mydomain.com. I have Apache 2.2 handling HTTP requests.

I am looking at sending synology HTTP to another computer and application HTTP request to the Apache computer but on a different port.

I have made the following changes in the Apache conf files, but this is not working.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
<VirtualHost *.80>
  ServerName application.mydomain.co.uk
  ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *.80>
  ServerName synology.mydomains.co.uk
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.3
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.3
</VirtualHost>

<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

Thanks.
David.

Comment: As simple as the :80… Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

instead of

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
```

What is more, I suggest you look into the log to see what Apache says.